# How to fix Function Query.where() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined error?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js, next-auth

Here is the my code:

```
import { useSession } from "next-auth/react";

const {data: session, status} = useSession();

const userChatRef = db
    .collection("chats")
    .where("users", "array-contains", session.user.email);
```

I got this error:

> FirebaseError: Function Query.where() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined

Comment: This is saying your `session.user.email` is not defined, so your problem is in your auth, not your query. You'll need to debug that.